# Writing exceptions for a VSTO plugin

Tags: vb.net, exception, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I've built a VSTO plugin for outlook using visual basic, and I want to write exceptions to the eventlog for future debugging. I used `My.Application.Log.WriteException(ex)`, however when I look at the event log, I can see the addin being loaded, but not the exception. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.logging.log.writeexception?view=netframework-4.8.

No idea where to go from here or what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Did you follow the relevant links from the page you linked to, e.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/log-info/walkthrough-determining-where-my-application-log-writes-information)?

Comment: Yes, it says to locate things in the config which I did. Apparently it writes to a file log but I don't know where that is for a VSTO addin that's run from visual studio and not yet deployed.